# PMD exclude not working

Tags: maven, pmd

I am trying to finetune our CI and I can't figure out how to avoid that PMD reports violations on generated code (not talking about Android R file there) in src-gen:

I used `mvn help:effective-pom` to verify my config, and the POM looks like I should. It point to right folder to exclude.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${pmd-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <linkXref>false</linkXref>
        <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
        <minimumTokens>${pmd.minimum.tokens}</minimumTokens>
        <targetJdk>${pmd.target.jdk}</targetJdk>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*R.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*Manifest.java</exclude>
            <excludeRoots>
                <excludeRoot>${basedir}/src-gen</excludeRoot>
            </excludeRoots>
        </excludes>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the example (end of the page) at the [PMD plugin Usage doc page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/usage.html) suggests that the `<excludeRoots>` part should be directly under `<configuration>`, not under `<excludes>`.

<del>If that does not help, maybe try `<excludeRoot>**/src-gen/**</excludeRoot>` instead.</del>

Comment: That's right. excludeRoots is a root configuration, not nested in excluded. Also Ant style ** does not work, and most importantly the root must be complete, it seems to be implemented as equals and not startsWith, so e.g. ONLY something exactly like this works: (This is all for current <version>3.6.)

    <excludeRoots>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/mdsal-binding</excludeRoots>