# PMD in eclipse does not accept exclude-pattern

Tags: eclipse, pmd

I am using PMD under eclipse 4.3.1 / Kepler and I cannot exclude files and folders from the violation check.

My folder structure

```
/any/path/to/the/workspace/myproject1
/any/path/to/the/workspace/myproject2
/any/path/to/the/workspace/myprojectWithPMDrulesFile/pmd-rules.xml
```

Now following folders get generated by testng

```
...../myproject1/test-output
...../myproject2/test-output
```

Now I have configured following rules file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     name="Xeno-PMD-rules"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>PMD Plugin preferences rule set</description>
    <exclude-pattern>.*/test-output/*.*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/.*/test-output/.*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>**/test-output/**</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>./test-output/.</exclude-pattern>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/android.xml/CallSuperFirst"/>
    ...
</ruleset>
```

In my case I have many hundred errors in the jquery.js file, which is in test-output.

**How can I exclude a specific folder and all files in it recursively?**

**How to set the pattern to work under eclipse and under ANT/maven?**

hint: seems to be similar to: [PMD exclude not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647771/pmd-exclude-not-working)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost got it already! Use the following exclusion syntax:

```xml
<exclude-pattern>.*/test-output/.*</exclude-pattern>
```

This will exclude all files that have `/test-output/` somewhere in their absolute path. The pattern is the same in Eclipse and Ant/Maven, as long as the excluded folders are also called `test-output`.

Additional explanations and examples can be found in the [PMD documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/howtomakearuleset.html#Excluding_files_from_a_ruleset).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [working set](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-working-set-and-how-do-i-use-it.html) with only the dir and files you want and set it under Project -> Properties -> PMD