# PMD exclude-pattern with gradle

Tags: gradle, pmd

I'm attempting to create some exclude patterns for a PMD task in Gradle.

My task is generated in the next way:

```
/* Allows generation of pmd config  */
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'pmd'
}
gradle.projectsEvaluated {

    subprojects.each() { project ->


        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {

            project.task("runPmd", type: Pmd) {

                description "Run pmd"
                group 'verification'

                source = fileTree("${project.projectDir}/src/main/java")
                ruleSetFiles = files("${project.rootDir}/build-tools/pmd.xml")
                ignoreFailures = true

                reports {
                    xml.enabled = true
                    html.enabled = true
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the ruleSet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset name="MyCompany ruleset"
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

    <description>
        MyCompany ruleset for Android PMD
    </description>

  <exclude-pattern>.*/org/jivesoftware/.*</exclude-pattern>
  <exclude-pattern>.*/net/java/.*</exclude-pattern>

...rules...
</ruleset>
```

But in my reports, I'm getting:
[image: Report]

Am I doing something wrong? Checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20189104/1668144) answer seems that I'm defining the `exclude-pattern` right, but pmd is analyzing those files.

Comment: This looks okay. Is your report surely up to date? Does it reference to correct rule file? Sorry for those stupid questions ;-) but the pattern looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've done a ./gradlew clean just to be sure that it is updated

Comment: Any include pattern floating around later in the rules file that could put the files in again?

Comment: No, I didn't copied the full file because there are a lot of rules, but there aren't include patterns in it

Comment: Is it checking all files in `.*/org/jivesoftware/.*` or just some?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and adding an empty `ruleSets []` property seemed to fix it for me.
Make sure to define the rules that you actually want to apply in your ruleset file - i.e. Move them from the `ruleSet` property block to the file (if you had any there).

This is what my task generation looks like:

```
// PMD
afterEvaluate {
    def variants = plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.application') ?
            android.applicationVariants : android.libraryVariants

    variants.each { variant ->
        def task = tasks.create("pmd${variant.name.capitalize()}", Pmd)

        task.group = 'verification'
        task.description = "Run PMD for the ${variant.description}."

        task.ruleSetFiles = files("pmd-ruleset.xml")
        task.ruleSets = []

        task.reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
        }

        def variantCompile = variant.javaCompile

        task.source = variantCompile.source

        task.dependsOn(variantCompile)
        tasks.getByName('check').dependsOn(task)
    }
}
```

I got the hint from this thread:
http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188193/thread/6e9c6017/

Answer (score 1):

```
Add below snippet in your build.gradle, you can exclude Classes and packages also
pmd {
    sourceSets = [ project.sourceSets.main ]
    ruleSetFiles = rootProject.files("codequality/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []

    pmdMain {
        excludes = [
                '**/Application.*',
                '**/jivesoftware/.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my [ruleset.xml](https://github.com/dgroup/arch4u-pmd#exclude-particular-folder-from-inspection) for Gradle [pmd](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html) plugin the following command works:

```xml
<ruleset name="Custom Rules">
  
    <!-- Exclude generated open api classes -->
    <exclude-pattern>.*/src/main/java/com/tbd/tbd/tbd/.*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>.*/src/main/java/com/tbd/tbd/tbd/tbd/.*</exclude-pattern>

    ...

</ruleset>
```

Could you please try the command below?

```xml
  ...
  <exclude-pattern>.*/src/main/java/net/java/.*</exclude-pattern>
  ...
```